# Transpone SQL columns without loss in performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, pivot, transform

I use SQL Server 2012. I have two large tables with data, as follows:

tableProjects (number of columns reduced for simplicity)

```
| ID | Name     |
| 1  | Project1 |
| 2  | Project2 |
| …  | …        |
| N  | ProjectN |
```

tableHours (number of process stages reduced to 3 for simplicity)

```
| ProjectID | ProcessStage | Hours |
| 1         | 1            | 10    |
| 1         | 2            | 20    |
| 1         | 3            | 30    |
| 2         | 1            | 40    |
| 2         | 2            | 50    |
| 2         | 3            | 60    |
| …         | …            | …     |
| N         | 1            | 70    |
| N         | 2            | 80    |
| N         | 3            | 90    |
```

I need to select this data in a way that each ProcessStage gets a separate column, so I transpone this data like so:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Name,
(SELECT Hours FROM tableHours WHERE ProcessStage = 1 AND ProjectID = p.ID) AS Hours1,
(SELECT Hours FROM tableHours WHERE ProcessStage = 2 AND ProjectID = p.ID) AS Hours2,
(SELECT Hours FROM tableHours WHERE ProcessStage = 3 AND ProjectID = p.ID) AS Hours3
FROM tableProjects p
```

And in fact I do get what I want:

```
| ID | Name     | Hours1 | Hours2 | Hours3 |
| 1  | Project1 | 10     | 20     | 30     |
| 2  | Project2 | 40     | 50     | 60     |
| …  | …        | …      | …      | …      |
| N  | ProjectN | 70     | 80     | 90     |
```

But in my case performance is very important, so I am thinking if there is a more productive way of doing this. If you know it, can you show me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation to pivot your data:

```
select 
    p.id
  , p.Name
  , Hours1 = max(case when h.ProcessStage = 1 then h.Hours end) 
  , Hours2 = max(case when h.ProcessStage = 2 then h.Hours end) 
  , Hours3 = max(case when h.ProcessStage = 3 then h.Hours end) 
from tableProjects p
  inner join tableHours h
    on h.Projectid = p.id
group by p.id, p.Name
```

You could use dynamic sql to automatically generate the columns needed for the pivot, but since you said that performance is very important, it may be best to hard-code it if possible.

Comment: Consider tableProjects is joined with couple of more tables as well as it has some more its own columns to select, say 10 more columns in total. Wouldn't GROUP BY all these columns reduce overall productivity compared to my way of selecting this data?

Comment: @B.Sverediuk Not at all. But since I don't have your data, why don't you test it and see? Check the execution plan and the query statistics time and io.

Comment: I'll try your way and compare the results. Whatever way is more eficient on my data will be used. Thanks.